# Что значат эти значения при установке IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Куда галочки тыкать? И что значат эти ".java/.groovy/.kt"?

[image: Установщик IDEA]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не по теме

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, это ассоциации с типами файлов, для которых действием по умолчанию будет запуск IDEA. Например, по клику на файле `*.java` в проводнике.

Comment: На Что посоветуете поставить галочку?

Comment: На те типы, для которых желательно действие "открыть в IDEA". На какие именно - решать только вам.

Answer (score 2):

Это ты включаешь аннотацию к данным файлам) Файлы с расширением `.java` , `.groovy` или `.kt` Будут открываться непосредственно в IntelliJ если поставить на него галочку.

Данный файл будет выглядеть вот так если поставить галочку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]